# Bootstrap Form Label and text box arrangement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<fieldset>
 <legend> Personal Details </legend> 
 <form class =" form-inline well span9" > 

  <label> Last Name </label> 

  <input type="text" class = "span2" placeholder = "Type Last Name"/> 

  <label> Middle Name </label> 

  <input type="text" class = "span2"/>  

  <label> First Name </label> 

  <input type="text" class = "span2"/><br/>

  <label> NickName</label> 

  <input type="text" class = "span2"/>

   <label>Gender</label>
          <span class="controls span2">  
     <select id="select01" style="width:100%;">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
     </select>
   </span> 

 </form>
```

What happens is that the label for Gender appears AFTER the Alias label and text field. Can someone please explain how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your form tag should come before the fieldset and legend. Also the span with class controls should probably be a DIV. See the Bootstrap Docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your form in question the following way :
Here's a jsfiddle for http://jsfiddle.net/shail/sGgKE/

Jsfiddle with 3 column form http://jsfiddle.net/shail/ykpr5/show

Edit : As per request in comment : Three column form with bootstrap

```
<form class="well span9">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Your First Name">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Your Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
         <label>Nickname</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" class="span3">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Your email address">
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="Gender" id="DropdownGender" class="span3">
            <option value="">Male</option>
            <option value="">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Regular form alignment

```
<div class="well span9">
<form id="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        <label>Last name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Smith" class="input-xlarge">
        <label>Middle Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="K" class="input-xlarge">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John" class="input-xlarge">
        <label>Nickname</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" class="input-xlarge">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="Gender" id="DropdownGender" class="input-xlarge">
            <option value="">Male</option>
            <option value="">Female</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: thaks for the answer. However, I was looking more along the lines of having 3 columns per row. How do you align your form at that point?

Comment: Do you want 3 columns like first name and last name in 1 col, 2nd col nick name and in 3rd col gender

Comment: @Stranger updated my answer plz check the jsfidlle as well . Thanks

Comment: Fantastic. You did it without any css. That's what I wanted. I just wanted to use bootstrap and align. Thanks alot.

Comment: So let's say if I later want four filelds in a row,instead of 3, what changes do I need to make to the code ? Will expanding the span to something bigger than 9 work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25189/discussion-between-shail-and-stranger)

Comment: Using nested divs you can incorporate 12 columns inside span 9 .